# Parse error at line x: Combination of ROLLUP and column expressions in a GROUP BY clause is not supported

Tags: azure-synapse

The following query works on onprem SQL DB as well as Azure SQL DB:

```
SELECT
    brand,
    category,
    SUM (sales) sales
FROM
    dbo.sales_summary
GROUP BY
brand, ROLLUP(category);
```

But when run on Azure Synapse Data Warehouse it returns the following error:

**Parse error at line: 9, column: 9: Combination of ROLLUP and column expressions in a GROUP BY clause is not supported.**

If I understand correctly, Synapse does not support partial ROLLUP and it needs to be replaced using something else.

Can someone please advise how do I re-write the above using CTE or other efficient method?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error as you are combining column expressions with Rollup while using the query as "brand" is being considered as a column expression.
You need to use the Rollup correctly like below and it should work in your case

```
SELECT
    brand,
    category,
    SUM (sales) sales
FROM
    dbo.sales_summary
GROUP BY ROLLUP(brand,category);
```

Please refer to the documentation [SELECT - GROUP BY- Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax)
[image]

I have tested Rollup in my Synapse environment and it works fine -
[image]